# Matlab: using textscan to read complex numbers

Tags: matlab, file, complex-numbers, textscan

I have a text file `cTest.dat` with a bunch of complex numbers in the following format:

```
(2.324,2432) (-1.24,-3.43) 
(2.4,0) (1.24,-8.85) 
(-2.324,4.56) (-1.24,-3.43)
```

and I'd like to read them into matlab. From the [help site](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) it seems `textscan` would be a good choice and I try

```
id2=fopen('cTest.dat');
C = textscan(id2, '(%f , %f)');
```

However this gives me

```
C = [6x1 double]    [6x1 double]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what is the format of id2?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you are expecting? Its a bit unclear to me what you want in the end...

Comment: @darthbith In the end I want to end up with complex numbers (in matlab: 2.324+2432i,...). I was hoping that the above would give me two vectors C(1) and C(2) containing the real and imaginary parts respectively so I could construct the complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need one more line:

```
C=complex(C{1,1},C{1,2})
```

Comment: I just used exactly your code and I got the same results as you: 2 cells with 6 doubles. By adding this code line, I got an array of 6 complex double numbers. I use matlab2013b.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong in the previous comment, it works for me too now. Sorry about that and thanks a lot!